# create oracle function to calculate fields based on excel formula

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case

need a bit of help. need to create a function within oracle package to calculate some column. The calculation is based on excel sheet and the excel formula is `=IF(A1=1,A2*0.1,IF(A1=2,A2*0.2,IF(A1=3,A2*0.4,IF(A1=4,A2*0.6,IF(A1=5,A2*0.8,)))))`to get the column value. So I would like to make these calculation inside my function in oracle. So far I have the folowing:

`FUNCTION GET_COST(
  p_parametr1    IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
  p_parametr2  IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
  p_parametr3 IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL
) RETURN NUMBER
AS
  BEGIN
   CASE 
    WHEN p_parametr1 = 1 THEN p_parametr2 * 0.1
    WHEN p_parametr1 = 2 THEN p_parametr2 * 0.2
    WHEN p_parametr1 = 3 THEN p_parametr2 * 0.4
    WHEN p_parametr1 = 4 THEN p_parametr2 * 0.6
    WHEN p_parametr1 = 5 THEN p_parametr2 * 0.8
  ELSE RETURN NULL
END CASE;
END GET_COST;`

So the value of parametr3 (column 3) is depends of sum of calculation in column 1 and column 2. But something is wrong with my function and just won't work. Maybe using then WHEN CASE is bad idea?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong - you need a `return` statement for the entire expression:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION GET_COST(
  p_parametr1    IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
  p_parametr2  IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
  p_parametr3 IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL
) RETURN NUMBER
AS
  BEGIN
   RETURN CASE 
    WHEN p_parametr1 = 1 THEN p_parametr2 * 0.1
    WHEN p_parametr1 = 2 THEN p_parametr2 * 0.2
    WHEN p_parametr1 = 3 THEN p_parametr2 * 0.4
    WHEN p_parametr1 = 4 THEN p_parametr2 * 0.6
    WHEN p_parametr1 = 5 THEN p_parametr2 * 0.8
  ELSE NULL
END;
END GET_COST;
```

Comment: `case` _expressions_ are terminated with `end` only; `end case` only applies to `case` _statements_.

Comment: Yikes! Copy paste bug. Thanks for noticing